# Bookmark to open new window and start playing radio station?

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I'm trying to make a bookmark so I can open BBC Radio 4 and have it automatically start playing in a new window.

So far I have:

```
javascript:void(win=window.open('https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_fourfm?URL='+location.href, 'Radio 4', 'width=369,height=630,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no'))
```

This opens the player in a new window, but doesn't start the radio playing. To do that I have to click a button in that window.

Is it possible to trigger that by adding more code to the bookmark code?

I'm not very good at coding, and it's been trial and error so far.... I think I might be able to use this somehow:-

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").click()
```

The button is in an element as follows:-

```
<div id="play-controls"> <button type="button" id="btn-play" title="Play"><span>Play</span></button> <button type="button" id="btn-pause" title="Pause"><span>Pause</span></button> <button type="button" id="btn-stop" title="Stop"><span>Stop</span></button> </div>
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Don't think you can do anything with bookmarklet once the page loads in a new tab. Check if there is a query paramerter like `autoplay=yes` or something like that similar to `resizable=yes`

Comment: @adiga - That's brilliant. autoplay=yes didn't work, but autoplay=1 did. Not sure why, but your reply was instrumental in my google-work!

Comment: That's great! You can either delete this question (since it has little to do with programming and more to do with BBC radio features. It's unlikely to help future readers). Or, if you do think it's useful here, you can post an answer and accept after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void(win=window.open('https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_radio_fourfm?URL='+location.href, 'Radio 4', 'width=369,height=630,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no,autoplay=1'))
```

This code was what I ended up using - it may be of use to other users since it demonstrates how to code a bookmarklet to open a link in a new window, resize it to dimensions (mine are specific to the site I was linking to) and autoplay the service I wanted on that site.

The only thing I have left to do is create a favicon - because chrome assigns all bookmarklets an unattractive icon that resembles a blank document.

I think I should be able to do it following instructions here:-

https://marcjenkins.co.uk/how-to-add-favicons-to-bookmarklets-in-chrome/

Essentially - find a page with a favicon you like, save it as a bookmark, export your entire set of bookmarks, look in the resultnt html page for the icon info of the bookmark of the site with the favicon you like, and copy and paste that into the details for your bookmarklet.

(Posting summary in case that link breaks in the future)